# Jest: Avoiding all the casting in typescript - is there a way?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have recently tried to apply jest into my typescript workflow.

I am using a standard

```
jest.mock("../logger.ts")
```

TO setup my mock but now to do some simple asserts, I am having to do the following.

```
expect(Logger).toBeCalledWith(category)
expect((Logger as jest.Mock<Logger>).mock.instances[0].addContext).toBeCalledTimes(2)
expect((Logger as jest.Mock<Logger>).mock.instances[0].addContext).toBeCalledWith("service", serviceDefinition)
expect((Logger as jest.Mock<Logger>).mock.instances[0].addContext).toBeCalledWith("stack", stackDefinition)
```

Wow :-(, So Logger cast to jest.mock and then get the instance for 0 (be nice if there was a first() or one() method) and then get the methods on the instance.

Anybody got a better way, am I doing this right ?

I suppose I could create a instance variable above and then I don't have to repeat the casting.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Here is the contents of the logger.ts

```
import { getLogger, Logger as Log4jLogger } from "log4js"

import { LogLevel } from "./log-level"

/**
 * Logger Instance Class - Represents an actual logger instance
 */

export class Logger {
  private logger: Log4jLogger

  /**
   * Create a Logger.
   */
  constructor(category?: string) {
    // Obtain logger and set default log level
    this.logger = getLogger(category)
  }

  /**
   * Get the current log level
   * @returns {LogLevel}
   */
  get level(): LogLevel {
    return (this.logger.level as any).levelStr as LogLevel
  }

  /**
   * Set the current log level
   * @param {LogLevel} level
   */
  set level(level: LogLevel) {
    this.logger.level = level
  }

  /**
   * Write a trace log message
   * @param {string} message
   * @param args
   */
  trace(message: string, ...args: any[]) {
    this.logger.trace(message, ...args)
  }

  isTraceEnabled(): boolean {
    return this.logger.isTraceEnabled()
  }

  /**
   * Write a debug log message
   * @param {string} message
   * @param args
   */
  debug(message: string, ...args: any[]) {
    this.logger.debug(message, ...args)
  }

  isDebugEnabled(): boolean {
    return this.logger.isDebugEnabled()
  }

  /**
   * Write a info log message
   * @param {string} message
   * @param args
   */
  info(message: string, ...args: any[]) {
    this.logger.info(message, ...args)
  }

  isInfoEnabled(): boolean {
    return this.logger.isInfoEnabled()
  }

  /**
   * Write a warn log message
   * @param {string} message
   * @param args
   */
  warn(message: string, ...args: any[]) {
    this.logger.warn(message, ...args)
  }

  /**
   *
   */
  isWarnEnabled(): boolean {
    return this.logger.isWarnEnabled()
  }

  /**
   * Write a error log message
   * @param {string} message
   * @param args
   */
  error(message: string, ...args: any[]) {
    this.logger.error(message, ...args)
  }

  isErrorEnabled(): boolean {
    return this.logger.isErrorEnabled()
  }

  /**
   * Write a fata log message
   * @param {string} message
   * @param args
   */
  fatal(message: string, ...args: any[]) {
    this.logger.fatal(message, ...args)
  }

  isFatalEnabled(): boolean {
    return this.logger.isFatalEnabled()
  }

  addContext(key: string, value: any): void {
    this.logger.addContext(key, value)
  }

  removeContext(key: string): void {
    this.logger.removeContext(key)
  }

  clearContext(): void {
    this.clearContext()
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant contents of your `logger.ts` module.

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question.